# search data frame 1 values in data frame 2 and count the occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames as below:
data frame df1 (with one column):

```
names
alpha beta
test1 test2
abc def
```

and data frame df2 (also with one column):

```
names
alpha beta (abc)
abc def d
abc def (xyz)
test1 test2
test1 test2 (a)
alpha beta d
alpha beta (1)
alpha beta (2)
```

I want output such that code will search df1 values in df2 and count the occurrence of those values to show the output as below.

Desired output data frame (two columns):

```
names          occurrence
alpha beta         4
test1 test2        2
abc def            2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replace` twice and `value_counts`

```
df1['name'].replace(df['names'].reset_index().set_index('names')['index'].to_dict(),regex=True).replace(df['names'].to_dict()).value_counts()
Out[268]: 
alpha beta     4
abc def        2
test1 test2    2
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Data input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['alpha beta','test1 test2','abc def']})

df1=pd.DataFrame({'name':['alpha beta (abc)','abc def d','abc def (xyz)','test1 test2','test1 test2 (a)','alpha beta d','alpha beta (1)','alpha beta (2)']})
```

Comment: Ah you fixed the input! I was wondering why I was getting 4 2 1 and not 4 2 2.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think there should be a typo ...if not, I think we need some fuzzy match here..

Comment: 99% sure it is a typo, unless OP clarifies ;-)

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly i was looking for.

Comment: @Anand yw~:-) have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.extract` + `value_counts` -

```
p = '(' + df1.names.str.cat(sep='|') + ')'
df2.names.str.extract(p, expand=False).value_counts()

alpha beta     4
abc def        2
test1 test2    2
Name: names, dtype: int64
```

If it's possible for multiple matches to occur for a given row, you can use `extractall` instead -

```
df2.names.str.extractall(p).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()

alpha beta     4
abc def        2
test1 test2    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```